# Binding to string property returning a formatted double

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

My current project is to maintain a WPF application which was not developed by me. The following scenario:

- Textbox with binding to a string property
- the string property encapsulates a double
- On set{} the string value gets `double.TryParse`'d
- On get{} the property returns a `string.Format("{0:N2}", _value)`
- The `TextBox` Binding needs the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

The problem is: If I type in a value without comma, everything works fine. But due to the returned `string.Format("{0:N2}", _value)` the value already has a comma. If I type in a comma, there are two comma of course. At this moment the `double.TryParse` within the set fails and I need to modify the textbox input with cursor.

I'm happy about any solution.

Comment: You can always add another line of code to your Setter that cleans spurious characters from the string.  Also consider a two way IValueConverter.

Comment: If you can change the model, I would do that.  Change the property type to double, and use `{Binding DoubleVal,StringFormat='{}{0:N2}'}` to display the proper number formatting.

Comment: IValueConverter could be an option. But it effects only one single view with one single `TextBox`. The rest is information. To change the valuetype from string to double would effect the whole application in an unpredictable way.

Comment: I think both solutions would work. I Changed something to the view itself in a way that LostFocus is the UpdateSourceTrigger. But if you write your suggestion as answer I will mark it as solution. (Especially the switch from string to double)